# Nim range out of bounds

Tags: arrays, nim-lang

So I'm new to Nim. Sorry if this sounds nooby. Here's my code:

```
proc makeMap(width: int, size: int): seq[int]=
 var theMap = newSeq[int](size)
 var playerPos: int = 249750
 var i: int = 0;
 for i in 1..size:
   if i<width:
     theMap[i] = 2
   elif i == playerPos:
     theMap[i] = 1
   else:
     theMap[i] = 0
 return theMap


var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var nsize: int = width * height
var myMap = makeMap(width, nsize)
echo "Map: ", myMap
```

And here's the error that I get:

```
nim.nim(18)              nim
nim.nim(8)               makeMap
system.nim(2833)         sysFatal
Error: unhandled exception: index out of bounds [IndexError]
```

What can I do to solve the error? Sorry, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You iterate `i` from 1 to `size` (inclusive), but the seq `theMap` has indices from 0 to `size-1`. Change line 5 to `for i in 0 .. size-1`, or you could also use `theMap.high` to find the highest allowed index.

Comment: Also, I prefer typing `for i in 0 ..< size` instead of `for i in 0 .. size-1`